# Probability your name will be drawn out of a hat without replacement

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, odds

Let's say you put your name in a hat with 7 other names (n=8). Only 4 names will be drawn from said hat. Each name will be drawn one at a time, without replacement. What is the probability that your name will be drawn?

I've googled a bit and most of my results lead me to the secret santa problem. Which is similar, but not answering the same question me thinks.

Is the answer 1/8 * 1/7 * 1/6 * 1/5 ?

Am I over complicating this? Does none of this matter and the probability is 4/8 = 50%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a sense you *are* over-complicating it, but it is still useful to be able to show that the intuitively correct answer corresponds to the correct answer under a draw-by-draw probability calculation.  Assuming simple random sampling without replacement, the probability that your name will be drawn is $4/8 = 0.5 = 50$%.

If you really want to see what happens when you break this probability calculation down onto a draw-by-draw basis, let $\mathcal{D}_i$ be the event that your name is drawn on the $i$th draw.  Under simple random sampling without replacement, the probability of being drawn in the first four draws is:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{D}_{1:4})
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}(\bar{\mathcal{D}}_{1:4}) \\[16pt]
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}(\bar{\mathcal{D}}_1 \cap \bar{\mathcal{D}}_2 \cap \bar{\mathcal{D}}_3 \cap \bar{\mathcal{D}}_4) \\[12pt]
&= 1 - \prod_{i=1}^4 \mathbb{P}(\bar{\mathcal{D}}_i | \bar{\mathcal{D}}_1 \cap \cdots \cap \bar{\mathcal{D}}_{i-1}) \\[12pt]
&= 1 - \frac{7}{8} \cdot \frac{6}{7} \cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{5} \\[12pt]
&= 1 - \frac{4}{8} \\[12pt]
&= \frac{4}{8} \\[12pt]
&= \frac{1}{2} = 0.5, \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

where the transition to the third line uses the [chain rule of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability)).  Or if you prefer to expand out based on probabilities of being drawn on the individual draws, you get:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{D}_{1:4})
&= \ \ \ \mathbb{P}({\mathcal{D}}_1 \cap \bar{\mathcal{D}}_2 \cap \bar{\mathcal{D}}_3 \cap \bar{\mathcal{D}}_4) 
+ \mathbb{P}(\bar{\mathcal{D}}_1 \cap {\mathcal{D}}_2 \cap \bar{\mathcal{D}}_3 \cap \bar{\mathcal{D}}_4) \\[6pt]
&\quad + \mathbb{P}(\bar{\mathcal{D}}_1 \cap \bar{\mathcal{D}}_2 \cap {\mathcal{D}}_3 \cap \bar{\mathcal{D}}_4) 
+ \mathbb{P}(\bar{\mathcal{D}}_1 \cap \bar{\mathcal{D}}_2 \cap \bar{\mathcal{D}}_3 \cap {\mathcal{D}}_4) \\[12pt]
&= \ \ \ \frac{1}{8} \cdot \frac{7}{7} \cdot \frac{6}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{5}
+ \frac{7}{8} \cdot \frac{1}{7} \cdot \frac{6}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{5} \\[6pt]
&\quad + \frac{7}{8} \cdot \frac{6}{7} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{5}
+ \frac{7}{8} \cdot \frac{6}{7} \cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{5} \\[12pt]
&= \ \ \ \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} \\[12pt]
&= \frac{4}{8} \\[12pt]
&= \frac{1}{2} = 0.5. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$